# Nodejs FS module returning no such file or dir error

Tags: node.js, filesystems, fs

Code:

```
fs.readdir('./commands/', (err, files) => {
     // Do something... 
});
```

Error:

> ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir './commands/'

The folder `./commands/` *does* exist. This file is `src/index.js` and is trying to read the directory of `src/commands/`. It wouldn't be `fs.readdir('/commands'` because that would be referring to the root directory of my PC (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, Node version v8.10.0). If any further information is required, ask and I will provide it.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try with __dirname:

```
fs.readdir(__dirname +'/commands/', (err, files) => {
// Do something... 
})
```