# Why does readdirSync() say no such file or directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js

index.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
```

filesystem:

```
src
-commands
  -stuff.js
-config.json
-index.js
```

Error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir './commands/'
    at Object.readdirSync (fs.js:783:3)
```

The folder is there, and has files in it.
I tried './commands/' , './commands' , 'commands' , nothing seems to work.

Comment: "./{DIRECTORY_NAME}" with the leading ./ works fine. I just tested it. Must be something else, like a misspelling.

Comment: Are you on Windows?  The Path delimeter on windows is "\".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nodejs FS module returning no such file or dir error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50966704/nodejs-fs-module-returning-no-such-file-or-dir-error)

Comment: I am on windows for local dev. I managed to solve the issue with:
```
path.resolve(commandsFolder)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try processing path with `path` module, as below

```js
const path = require('path');

const dirPath = path.resolve(__dirname, './commands');
```

And then pass `dirPath` to `readdirSync`function.
`path` is an internal node.js module, so you don't need to install anything

Comment: I just found this right before your answer. You are 100% correct. I didn't realize between Windows (local) and Ubuntu(remote server) that the paths would not resolve correctly without this.

Answer (score 4):

You are on Windows.  The path delimeter for Windows is `\`, not `/`.  Try making your program platform agnostic with something like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require("path");

const commandDir = path.join(__dirname, "commands");
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandDir).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

console.log(commandFiles);
```

Answer (score 0):

**With RegEx**

```
const fs = require('fs');

let searchPath = "./mydirectory";
let searchFileName = ".*myfile.*";

let searchFoundFiles = fs
    .readdirSync(searchPath)
    .filter((f) => new RegExp(searchFileName).test(f));

if (searchFoundFiles.length) {
    console.log("File already exists");
}
```